# Escape in systemd.timer

Tags: systemd

I have trouble to escape the following part of my systemd.timer

```
--files-from=<(ssh -p 182 web-iot.com 'find  /mnt/backups/postgresql/box/snapshots/ -mtime -7 -type f -exec basename {} \;') \
```

tried so far:

```
--files-from=\\\<(ssh -p 182 web-iot.com \\\'find  /mnt/backups/postgresql/box/snapshots/ -mtime -7 -type f -exec basename {} \;\\\') \
```

without success, i could use a shell file but i think it should be possible.

Full systemd.timer exec:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rsync \
  --verbose \
  --archive \
  --times \
  --partial \
  --delete \
  --progress \
  --bwlimit=7000 \
  --rsh="ssh -p 182" \
  --files-from=\\<(ssh -p 182 web-iot.com 'find  /mnt/backups/postgresql/box/snapshots/ -mtime -7 -type f -exec basename {} \;') \
web-iot.com:/mnt/backups/postgresql/box/snapshots/ \
  /var/lib/postgresql/backups/box
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete line? Including which systemd directive you're using?

Comment: added full comand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<( )` is [process substitution](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process_Substitution), it's a special Bash syntax (also in some other shells, but not in dash). Systemd doesn't use a shell to run the command in `Exec*` lines, and it only does some minimal processing itself (including very specific variable expansion, templating, etc.).

So you cannot use `<( )` in the `ExecStartPre` line directly. At the very least, you'll have to wrap it in a shell:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/rsync \
  --verbose \
  --archive \
  --times \
  --partial \
...
```

(and escape accordingly). Then systemd will run bash, and bash will process the process substitution.

But it would be better to use a shell script here.